# How to convert a higher order SDE to a system of first order SDE's?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider the following stochastic differential equation:
$$\ddot{X_t}+\omega_0^2X_t=dW_t.$$
I thought the way to do this would be to let:
$$dX_t=\dot{X}_tdt,$$
$$d\dot{X}_t=-\omega_0^2X_tdt+dW_t,$$
however, this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056792/how-to-code-oscillator-driven-by-gaussian-white-noise-edit-how-to-convert-ode) says that the system of equations should be this:
$$dX_t=\dot{X}_tdt+dW_t,$$
$$d\dot{X}_t=-\omega_0^2X_tdt.$$
The way it is done in that post seems to be correct as they are able to reproduce theoretical results numerically.

Edit:

The code in the linked post does not work if I switch the force vector around? Do you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: It seems incorrect to me, the regularity is wrong. $X_t$ should be classically differentiable (once, not twice). A simpler scenario in which you can see that this is wrong would be $\ddot{X}_t=\dot{W}_t$, which is to be interpreted as $X_t=x_0+tv_0+\int_0^t W_s ds$ (where $x_0$ is the initial condition for position and $v_0$ is the initial condition for velocity).

Comment: In the notation of the answer you referred to the issue is simply that $dW_t$ should be in the second component of the forcing vector.