# Solve Langevin equation with blue noise?

Tags: stochastic-processes, physics, stochastic-calculus, signal-processing, noise

I would like to solve the following Langevin equation
$$\frac{d^2 x}{d t^2}+\omega_0^2x(t)=\eta(t),$$
where $\eta(t)$ is a blue noise signal given by
$$\eta(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{\eta}(f)\exp(2\pi i t f) df,$$
and $\hat{\eta}(t)$ is the fourier transform given by
$$\hat{\eta}(f)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \eta(t)\exp(-2\pi i t f) dt,$$
such that $|\hat{\eta}(f)|=D\sqrt{|f|}$, where $D$ is a constant which gives a measure of the strength of the signal. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem) the autocorrelation is given by
$$\begin{aligned}
R_{\eta \eta}(\tau)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty|\hat{\eta}(f)|^2\exp(2\pi i \tau f) df,\\
&= \frac{D^2}{2\pi^2\tau^2},
\end{aligned}$$
where the Fourier transform is calculated using an identity in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions,_one-dimensional).
[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3046802/will-the-energy-of-a-randomly-driven-harmonic-oscillator-grow-to-infinity-or-osc) shows that the variance is given by
$$\begin{aligned}
\langle x^2(t) \rangle &= \frac{1}{\omega_0^2}\int_0^t\int_0^t \sin[\omega_0(t-t')]\sin[\omega_0(t-t'')]R_{\eta\eta}(t'-t'')dt''dt' \\
&= \frac{D^2}{2\pi\omega_0^2}\int_0^t\int_0^t \frac{\sin[\omega_0(t-t')]\sin[\omega_0(t-t'')]}{(t'-t'')^2}dt''dt'.
\end{aligned}$$
This integral is not defined at $t'=t''$, does this mean we cannot calculate the solution for the case where $\eta(t)$ is blue noise or have I made a mistake in the maths?

Comment: So the auto correlation $R$ at $\tau=0$ is $-\infty$?

Comment: Yes but that makes sense right? The autocorrelation at $\tau=0$ gives the variance. The power spectrum is given by $S_{\eta\eta}(f)=D^2|f|$, so all frequencies have non-zero energy associated with them. Therefore we expect the energy or the variance of $\eta(t)$ to be infinite. The white noise driver in the linked post is also infinite for $\tau=0$.

Comment: I think it should be $+\infty$ and I have now edited the main post.

Comment: If you are trying to solve an equation with infinite noise, you shouldn't be surprised you get strange results. What happens if you regularize the noise, say work with $R(\tau)\sim {1\over \tau_{0}^{2}+\tau^2} $?

Comment: I guess I am hopeful that given white noise works okay, maybe blue noise works as well.

Comment: Also, can you point out which formula you used to calculate $R$, I couldn't find it in the table you linked to .

Comment: I used 311 in that table.

Comment: Not valid for $\alpha=1$

Comment: You are right, however, we can derive it using $|x|=x\,\text{sgn}(x)$, then using 109, 308 and 312.

Comment: still think a $\delta$ function is missing. Consider the $FT$ of $\alpha\rightarrow 0$ limit of ${\exp^{-\alpha |x|}\over \alpha}$

Comment: Thank you that is a really good idea. I guess you mean $[1-\exp(-\alpha |x|)]/\alpha$? That does give a delta function.

Comment: Yes, I picked the one without, to show you that its FT goes to $1/w^2$, so that  $1/w^2$ cannot represent $|x|$ without some extra $\delta$

Comment: Do you know if there is a simpler form for the Fourier transform of $|x|$ because that would make the integral easier?